# Haskell spitting out wrong numbers at random

Tags: haskell

I am just starting to learn functional programming, My pick is haskell.
It's been ok for a few days until something bizzare happen in the console

At first I thought the tutorial ( http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out ) is wrong

```
Prelude> [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]  
[(1,1,1)]
```

It should be `(3,4,5)` and `(4,6,8)`. 
I tried `3^2+5^2`, it spits out this bulks of numbers ( something like 60 rows of numbers, around 3000 digits ); `4^2+3^2` seems to produce the same numbers.

Trying to add any numbers the result will be `100`

```
Prelude> 100 + 200
100
Prelude> 300 + 500
100
```

I close the window and re-open it and the problem is solved.

Does this miscalculation often happened in Haskell? or perhaps my version of Haskell is corrupted when downloading? or Any chance this is a rare bug?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do something like `let a + b = 100` prior to running that line? I can't replicate your results, and `let` definitions in ghci are kinda stateful.

Comment: Also, the correct output should probably be `[(3,4,5),(6,8,10)]`, which is what I get (and matches both the Wikipedia page and my maths education as being the first 2 Pythagorean triples)

Comment: @BluePeppers I think you've got it, because after `let a+b = 100`, that list comprehension *does* give `[(1,1,1)]`.

Comment: Wait, that's not just `let a+b=100`, although that *does* trigger it. This behavior is *bizarre*.

Comment: Oh wait now I understand.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: `let _ + _ = constant` changes the fixity (level) of `(+)`, so `a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 == a ^ ((2 + b) ^ 2) == (a ^ (constant ^ 2))`.

Comment: To OP: Make sure you include the _whole_ session to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is happening, as @BluePeppers suggested, is that you have somehow done the equivalent of `let a+b = 100` in ghci, after which it uses that definition instead of the usual `+` in all your expressions.

You might still wonder why that gives such enormous numbers, and so did I until I realized the second point: Redefining `(+)` also redefines its *precedence*, to the default of 9 (highest).  So your examples become interpreted as:

```
[ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

becomes

```
[ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^100^2 == c^2]
```

and

```
3^2+5^2
```

becomes

```
3^100^2
```

Comment: Oh that's even better than I expected. How lovely

Comment: aah, I didn't know haskell can override an operator.

Comment: I thought that haskell can solve aljebra problem then I tried that before trying the tutorial,